# Rvest and Google News Web Scraping: Not Working

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest, xml2

I am new to web scraping, and the below code is producing an empty character vector, and not sure how to resolve:

```
google_url <- "https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB:en"
google <- read_html(google_url)
articles <- google %>% html_nodes('.VDXfz') %>% html_text()
articles
```

Comment: You can get the links to webpages through `html_nodes('.VDXfz') %>% html_attr('href')` wasn't able to get the headlines though.

Comment: Be sure to let us know the packages you are attempting to use. library(rvest)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following will fetch you all the headlines from current loaded page. You would need `RSelenium` to if you need to scroll and further extract data.

```
library(rvest)
url = 'https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB:en'

url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.lBwEZb') %>% 
  html_nodes('.DY5T1d') %>% 
  html_text()

[1] "Liz Truss to hold Brexit talks with EU over NI protocol"                                                                             
 [2] "Lord Frost: I didn't support PM's coercive Covid plan"                                                                               
 [3] "David Frost: I never disagreed with Boris Johnson over Brexit policy – only coercive Covid rules"                                    
 [4] "Look at the lauding of David Frost and see a government deranged by the poison of Brexit"                                            
 [5] "What happened to the amiable, hard-working David Frost I once knew?"                                                                 
 [6] "COVID-19: Omicron now dominant variant in US after making up 73% of new cases, says CDC"
```